# DeviceControllerApplicationConnectionFailed in google chromecast

Tags: ios, iphone, chromecast, google-cast

I am integrating Google Chromecast in my videoplayer app. I have referred this link:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate

It displays Chromecast device but when I am trying to connect that device it returns an error. Here is the error log:

```
 -[GCKEventLogger logDeviceController:sessionID:application:connectionFailedWithError:]  LOG EVENT: DeviceControllerApplicationConnectionFailed device=<0x1311cc710:GCKDevice> [com.google.cast.CastDevice] 'Chrome Cast IBL' 192.168.1.185:8009 (e8fc847534f5fcb8e8c7190dc05458b6), sessionID=1272110429, appID=F1D64732, error=2
```

Any idea what would cause this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: googlecast demo app link please refere it https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type Problem occur because of slow internet connection then its take more time to connect with Chromecast so because of timeout its Failed to connect. So you need to reconnect(stop casting and connect again) then it easily connect with chromecast.

Comment: i have satisfied internet speed but i getting same issue with chromecast :(

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate) properly but the error still occurs, try the official [troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/chromecast/troubleshooter/2995236?hl=en). Also make sure that your device has a [supported operating system](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/2998456?hl=en) to install the Google Cast extension. You can check on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/_FZHQUQ5zEQ) for more workaround that can help you.